# Ember: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "apollo-cache"

Tags: ember-cli, broccolijs

I have tried to run an older ember project.
I have updated the project with yarn and after tried and run it with **ember serve**

When I try and run the app on localhost:4200 I get the following error in the console and the screen in the view is grey:

Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "apollo-cache"
at webpackMissingModule

I am not sure what is happening and if dependencies are correct.

From:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Small description for goes here",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "start": "ember server",
    "test": "ember test",
    "schema": "node retrieve-fragment-types.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "apollo-absinthe-upload-link": "^1.2.2",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.2.9",
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.5",
    "ember-ajax": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-apollo-client": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-auto-import": "^1.2.20",
    "ember-body-class": "^1.1.3",
    "ember-cli": "3.3.0",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^3.1.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^6.8.2",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy-build": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy-cloudfront": "^1.1.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy-display-revisions": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy-gzip": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy-revision-data": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy-s3": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy-s3-index": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-eslint": "^4.2.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^2.0.3",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^1.0.2",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.1",
    "ember-cli-json-module": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-moment-shim": "^3.1.0",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^4.0.1",
    "ember-cli-sass": "^7.0.0",
    "ember-cli-shims": "^1.0.2",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-composable-helpers": "^2.0.3",
    "ember-crumbly": "ivanvanderbyl/ember-crumbly#use-router-infos-for-crumb-generation",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-fetch": "^5.1.1",
    "ember-href-to": "^1.15.1",
    "ember-leaflet": "^3.0.11",
    "ember-leaflet-marker-cluster": "^0.2.0",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-moment": "^7.3.0",
    "ember-paper": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
    "ember-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "ember-simple-auth": "^1.2.2",
    "ember-source": "~3.3.1",
    "ember-truth-helpers": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-uploader": "^2.0.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.9.2",
    "graphql-tools": "^3.1.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.0.3",
    "loader.js": "^4.2.3",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.13"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@sentry/browser": "^5.5.0",
    "@sentry/integrations": "^5.5.0"
  }
}
```

To:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Small description for goes here",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "start": "ember server",
    "test": "ember test",
    "schema": "node retrieve-fragment-types.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "apollo-absinthe-upload-link": "^1.2.2",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.2.9",
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.5",
    "ember-ajax": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-apollo-client": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-auto-import": "^1.2.20",
    "ember-body-class": "^1.1.3",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^3.1.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^6.8.2",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy-build": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy-cloudfront": "^1.1.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy-display-revisions": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy-gzip": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy-revision-data": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy-s3": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy-s3-index": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-eslint": "^4.2.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^2.0.3",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^1.0.2",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.10.1",
    "ember-cli-json-module": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-moment-shim": "^3.1.0",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^4.0.1",
    "ember-cli-shims": "^1.0.2",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-composable-helpers": "^2.0.3",
    "ember-crumbly": "ivanvanderbyl/ember-crumbly#use-router-infos-for-crumb-generation",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-fetch": "^5.1.1",
    "ember-href-to": "^1.15.1",
    "ember-leaflet": "^3.0.11",
    "ember-leaflet-marker-cluster": "^0.2.0",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-moment": "^7.3.0",
    "ember-paper": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
    "ember-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "ember-simple-auth": "^1.2.2",
    "ember-source": "~3.3.1",
    "ember-truth-helpers": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-uploader": "^2.0.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.9.2",
    "graphql-tools": "^3.1.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.0.3",
    "loader.js": "^4.2.3",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.13",
    "sass": "^1.43.4",
    "apollo-cache": "^1.3.5",
    "ember-cli": "^3.28.3",
    "ember-cli-sass": "^10.0.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@sentry/browser": "^5.5.0",
    "@sentry/integrations": "^5.5.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Currently I am also looking for an answer. 
Update node to v14.x and Ember-cli to v4.2